# Fetching a KB hotfix in C#

Tags: c#, windows-update, hotfix

I'm trying to fetch a certain hotfix (KB976477) from a C# program. Using the WUApi (Windows Update Agent Api) is not working so far because the IUpdateSearcher.Search method only provides Software and Drivers which would be available via the normal Windows Update.
Given the name of the API this is not that much of a surprise...

Any idea how to fetch and install the aforementioned KB hotfix? Making an installer and giving the hotfix as a prerequesite is not really an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do this in an automated way. That hotfix is not available for download. You must contact MS directly to obtain it, as can be gleaned from the [hotfix description](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976477).

Comment: Holy crap. Thanks! This is not really helping me but explains why finding anything about how to obtain that hotfix automatically failed so far.